# Windows 8 Video Card Fried, onboard video not working in normal mode, only safe mode

Tags: windows, boot, video, graphics-card, windows-8.1

I recently experienced a catastrophic failure due to a large static shock from my body to my computer, causing the OS to freeze, and restart, and then my computer would not boot anymore. I removed my video card, and then my computer would boot up. However, I cannot boot Windows 8 into Normal Mode, but only in Safe Mode. I can see the Windows 8 startup logo spinning around, but once the login screen is supposed to show, the monitor turns off and says that the screen is not receiving a signal.

I can boot into Safe Mode with Networking, and any other safe mode, and do whatever I need to do, but no dice on the Normal Mode. I can also load up Linux Mint from a flash stick and see all my drives and such, and utilize my computer.

TLDR, I believe that my video drivers need to be removed, reconfigured, or something, but I'm not sure how to do that from Safe Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Safe Mode, try changing the screen resolution, and then boot into normal mode.

Or in Safe mode, install the [latest] driver for your onboard video.

Comment: That was it. I had to disable my video card drivers, and update/install the drivers for the on-board video card. Then, I had to also plug in both monitors even though the on-board only supports one being plugged in at a time. Thank you!